# How is this SQL statement done with Entity Framework? SUM column in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

This is my table:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/URpEI.png]

How is this SQL statement done with Entity Framework:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiqTs.png]

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method Syntax:**

```
var result = yourTable.GroupBy(i => i.ProductoId)
                           .Select(g => (g.Key,g.Sum(ing => ing.SumaUnidadesIngresados))
```

**Query syntax:**

```
var result = from i in ingresosStock
             group i by i.ProductoId into gr
             select (gr.Key, gr.Sum(s => s.SumaUnidadesIngresados))
```